# KnockOut.JS optionsText

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this code:

```
self.Groups = ko.observableArray();
function LoginNameObject(name) {
    this.loginName = name;
}

self.Groups.push(new LoginNameObject('Blah'));
```

I am trying to bind in the html like this:

```
 <select data-bind="options: Groups, optionsText: loginName"></select>
```

but keep on getting loginName is undefined when it tries to bind.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the `optionsText` you need to specify your property name is a **string**.

So you need to write

```
<select data-bind="options: Groups, optionsText: 'loginName'"></select>
```

See also in the documentation: [Example 3: Drop-down list representing arbitrary JavaScript objects, not just strings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#example-3-drop-down-list-representing-arbitrary-javascript-objects-not-just-strings)

Alternatively if you need a more complex logic to calculate the option text you can also specify the `optiosText` as a function:

```
<select 
   data-bind="options: Groups, optionsText: function(item) { return item.loginName }">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was a quick fix!